# Display last n lines of the output of a command

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, tail

I am trying to run `docker build` command. I wanted to see only last 'n' lines of the output continuously. For example, usual docker build command give me something like:

```
Building myimage
Step 1/15 : FROM python:3.6.9
 ---> 5bf410ee7bb2
Step 2/15 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Running in 201dd686c5d9
Removing intermediate container 201dd686c5d9
 ---> 298d3c728059
Step 3/15 : COPY . .
 ---> a47754a932c3
Step 4/15 : RUN chmod 755 /launch/start-script.sh
 ---> Running in ef27984abecf
Removing intermediate container ef27984abecf
 ---> ae13426f44e9
Step 5/15 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
...
...
...
```

Desired output for `n=3` is

```
Removing intermediate container ef27984abecf
 ---> ae13426f44e9
Step 5/15 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
```

I tried piping it to tail,

```
docker build | tail -3
```

but this shows last 3 lines once the build is finished. Is it possible to continuously display just last 'n' lines while the processes is running?

Comment: It looks like you want a short window to display it in. I wonder if there is a virtual window program that will run in a (virtual) terminal. I seem to remember something from a long long time ago.It would have to redraw the screen. I know curses can do it, but that is a programming library. However there may be a program that does it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I agree, I was thinking about redrawing the screen but seems a little overkill to use curses (or any library from python, perl etc) for solving simple problem. But I understand your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
i=0
[ "$#" = 1 ] || { >&2 echo "The number of lines should be provided"; exit 9; }
nlines=$1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    clear
    all="$all
$line"
    i=$((i+1))
    if [ "$i" -ge "$nlines" ]; then
        all="${all#*
}"
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$all"
done
```

Make it executable (`chmod +x nlines.sh`) and then, to continuously print only 3 lines,

```
docker build | ./nlines.sh 3
```

---

- `clear` clears the screen. That is done whenever a line comes from stdin.
- This adds the newly read line to variable `all`:

```
all="$all
$line"
```

- `[ "$i" -ge "$nlines" ]` tests if the maximum number of lines to be displayed were reached. If yes,

  - This removes the oldest line from the variable.

```
all="${all#*
}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I developed a utility for watching program output called [`pw` (Pipe Watch)](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/pw/about/).

The basic gist of it is not that different from the shell script in the accepted answer: the program continuously reads everything from standard input, and updates a display by repositioning the cursor (ANSI sequences) and repainting the lines.

`pw` pumps the lines through a small FIFO buffer, which is sampled according to several different disciplines, based on which mode it is in. Because it doesn't retain all the data which is passing through it, the program runs in a small, fixed amount of RAM.

`pw` is integrated with POSIX job control. When you put it in the background and tell it to execute (or start the job in the background) it still reads its input, but refrains from updating the terminal display (doing which would result in a `SIGTTOU` signal). In background operation, triggers are still running, and snapshots of the FIFO are taken. When you bring it to the foreground, the display is repainted. Thus, in one shell session, you can juggle numerous jobs which you can keep on eye on with `pw`. In the background, they don't block because something is reading their output.

`pw` gives you a stack of grep patterns that you can edit on the fly to filter the input before it arrives in the FIFO.

You can set a trigger for capturing snapshots of the FIFO for
display. There is a 19-deep snapshot history. A trigger consists of patterns
which match on specific lines of the FIFO. Triggers can make the display
appear to "freeze", if you use them to latch on to a repeating pattern, just
like how an oscilloscope's triggering makes a periodic waveform appear to stand still.

The view can be split into two or three variably sized and positioned vertical panes. The left pane shows a prefix of the lines, the middle pane an arbitrary middle portion, and the right pane shows the rest of the line after the prefix horizontally scrollable.

Comment: This works great in Linux. Would be great if it was incorporated into a common package like "moreutils" that I could install without building, and even better if it works in macOS and available thru Homebrew (it builds with some warnings; it runs as far as showing the help text, but I don't see output the way I see in Linux).

Comment: @Erhhung Someone tried to package it for Debian last summer, but ran into Debian stupidity and seems to have given up. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1017804   It looks like it is in Guix. https://issues.guix.gnu.org/56378

Comment: @Erhhung I have an old MacOS 10.4.7 (Lion) VM that I use for maintaining the MacOS port of the TXR language. (The Homebrew people package that, so it's better to use their build, probably). I could try buiding pw to see what is wrong on MacOS.

Comment: @Erhhung Turns out, I have a pw repo on that old MacOS vm; 30 commits out of date. I updated and rebuilt it.  It doesn't seem to be working right; the display doesn't refresh unless I hit a key; triggers do not trigger.

Comment: @Erhuhg and everyone else, the issue is that the `poll()` function returns immediately when a TTY descriptor is present, with a value of `32` in `revents` (not one of the events asked for). This happens without any input. So it then hangs reading a TTY character.   The Mac OS `poll` man page says "*BUGS*: the poll() system call currently does not support devices."

Comment: @Erhung I released PW version 4, which works on my very old version of MacOS. I can set triggers, split views, resize the terminal.  I saw a segfault on resizing, one time.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can do this easily with `tput`. I've created a zsh function that tails the last n lines of a command without clearing your screen. I've only tested this on an m1 mac running MacOS 12.6 Monterey.

```
function tail_lines () {
  # save cursor position
  tput sc
  tput ed

  # if is a number
  # `<->' is a special zsh pattern to match any number, an extension of forms like `<1-100>' which matches any number in the range 1 to 100 inclusive
  # https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide03.html
  if [[ "$1" = <-> ]]; then
    nlines=$1
  else
    nlines=5
  fi

  YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
  NORMAL_COLOR=$(tput sgr0)
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    # restore cursor position
    tput rc
    if [ -z "$output" ]; then
      output="  $line"
    else
      output=`echo "$output\n  $line" | tail -n $nlines`
    fi
    printf -- "${YELLOW}$output${NORMAL_COLOR}\n"
  done < /dev/stdin
  tput rc
  tput ed || tput 'cd'
}
```

### Usage

`brew update | tail_lines`

or
`brew update | tail_line 10`

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
docker build > logfile &
tail -3 -f logfile
```

-f does what you want, but it does not work on pipes, so intermediate file is needed.

Comment: Since this is printing last 3 lines of  logfile using tail command, it appends to the screen and hence display's the entire logs.