# How to 'tail' a logfile, X lines at a time

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, tail

I have a logfile that is generating hundreds of lines per second – say, 12 specific lines, 16× per sec.

I want to run either a command-line or a shell script that can display this logfile neatly in real-time.  But if I run `tail -f logfile.txt`, the text rapidly scrolls off the terminal window and can't be read by human eyes.  I haven't yet mastered the command line so this is all I can think of doing right now.

I want the terminal window to just print 12 lines at a time and automatically refresh, something like:

```
// while ( Ctrl+C hasn't been hit )
// {
//   clear terminal window
//   print last 12 lines of logfile.txt
//   wait until logfile is 12 lines longer
// }
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: it turns out I can do `tail -f logfile.txt` and just set the terminal window height to 12.  This gets me pretty close to what I want, but it seems like a "naive" approach.  Hoping somebody has a more elegant solution.

Comment: The description conflicts with itself. Your while loop would be run 16 times/s. How would you read 12 lines in a fraction of second? I recommend you to use the scroll lock key.

Comment: I have recently answered https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/598508, is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the last N lines at a M second interval using `watch`. Assuming N=20 and M=3,

```
watch -n3 tail -n20 logfile.txt
```

Obviously you'll lose great chunks of output as the update interval exceeds the write interval, but as far as I understand it this is what you want.

Comment: "The command will not allow quicker than 0.1 second interval" -- but otherwise, very much what I was looking for

Comment: I thought you wanted to be able to read the output, in which case wouldn't 0.1s be too fast?

Answer (score 1):

Bash >= 4 has a special built-in function `mapfile`:

```bsh
tail -f logfile.txt | while mapfile -t -n 12 lines && ((${#lines[@]})); do
    clear
    printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"
    sleep 0.1 # Might be necessary or you won't see anything at all except the last batch of lines
done
```

Adopted from: [Read n lines at a time using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314499/read-n-lines-at-a-time-using-bash).

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `less` for looking at logs. Some useful less commands:

- <kbd>G</kbd> to jump down to the last line
- <kbd>R</kbd> to refresh the file (followed after by `G`)
- <kbd>F</kbd> to tail the file in real time (aka `tail -f`): hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to stop tailing.

Comment: Ha, I read that too fast--I thought you wrote: "some less useful commands". Pays to read slower!

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f logfile.txt | less
```

And you can use the interface glenn jackman highlighted to move about:

- <kbd>F</kbd> to follow
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to stop following
- <kbd>q</kbd> to quit
- <kbd>/</kbd> to search for regular expressions